# Who captained Gryffindor during the final game in Half-Blood Prince?

Tags: harry-potter, quidditch

Harry was put in detention by Snape for using the Sectumsempra curse on Malfoy. So Ginny had to play seeker in the last game. As Harry was the captain of the side before he was made unavailable due to detention, who captained Gryffindor in the final game?

Answer (score 8):

There is no record in the book of who captained Gryffindor on the pitch. In fact, we can't even be sure that *anyone* captained Gryffindor on the pitch. Granted, the rules of Quidditch assume the existence of team captains: I distinctly remember one passage from *Quidditch Through the Ages* where it said that if the Snitch is not caught, the match can be ended by the mutual agreement of the two captains. (Unfortunately, I don't have a copy of the book to hand at the moment.) But that is different from saying that the captain must be on the pitch at all times, or that a substitute captain must be appointed if the real captain is not present. It is possible that Harry retained his full "captaincy" even in the middle of his detention. We simply don't have enough information.

In a larger sense, it doesn't really matter who was captain during the match, if anyone. Most of a Quidditch captain's work, as we see across multiple books, is done outside of matches: leading training sessions, recruiting players, plotting strategies, and generally laying the groundwork for a successful team. Once the match begins, competent players don't necessarily need an official on-field leader to carry out their roles effectively.

Comment: I'm assuming they had a captain pro-tem, probably Ginny.

Comment: Don't the captains shake hands at the beginning of each match? It's a minor thing, but you'd want *somebody* to do it.